JavaScript Pass a (new class) as a parameter
How do I pass a (new class) as a parameter to a button component without the function executing without click event is triggered.
class cDevice {
    new() { 
        //something here;
    }
}

device: {
    // the (new cDevice).new() is what I want to pass.
    createNew: function () { (new cDevice).new() }, 
}

This is the parameter will be used for, execute (new cDevice).new() when button click event is triggered.
"<button onclick=" + device.createNew + ">new</button>"

Thank you!

By not using strings for markup generation, but eg. document.createElement and addEventListener instead.

For this you have to pass a function reference on "onclick" event, not to actually invoke the function at this moment. f you directly call the function device.createNew(), it means it would be executed when the page loads..


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Button Click Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
// Define cDevice class
class cDevice {
    // The 'new' method inside cDevice class, logs when called
    new() { 
        console.log('New device created'); // Log a message when a new device is created
    }
}

// Define device object with method to create new device
const device = {
    createNew: function() { 
        // This creates a new cDevice instance and calls its 'new' method
        new cDevice().new(); // Calls the 'new()' method of the new device instance
    }
};

// The function that gets triggered when the button is clicked
function handleClick() {
    // When the button is clicked, this calls the 'createNew' method of device object
    device.createNew(); // This calls device.createNew(), which creates a new cDevice and calls its 'new()'
}

// Wait until the HTML page is fully loaded before attaching the click event
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Find the button with id 'myButton' in the HTML
    const button = document.querySelector('#myButton');
    
    // Attach an event listener to the button for the 'click' event
    button.addEventListener('click', handleClick); // When button is clicked, call 'handleClick' function
});
</script>

<!-- This is the button that will trigger the event -->
<button id="myButton">Create New Device</button>

</body>
</html>



I just delayed the execution of creating a new device until the button is clicked. If I call device.createNew() directly using onclick event, it runs immediately after the webpage finishes loading. So, i made like it's only runs when user clicked the button.

Thank you, I tried this solution, but I think if there is a more effective and faster solution without addEventListener, the button even click event will be any component/event because it will be generated dynamically.

document.body.innerHTML += "link"; - link, fixed my question.
